# Make TextView font look identical to Material Light AlertAialog's message area font

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

How do I style text in a TextView object to look identical to a stock material light AlertDialog? See image for more details. I do understand that if I spent enough time I probably could mimic the look but its better to get OS provided theme and not hardcode things. Bonus points if you are able to help me figure out how to get the default padding too.

I'm able to style identically to a stock material AlertDialog's **title** using this handle

> android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.DialogWindowTitle"

But I can't find the equivalent of this for a Material Light AlertDialog's **message** (the area circled in red)

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks so much!

Comment: By default same `font` is used by android studio sdk in whole project.

Comment: turns out it is very close but not exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making an alert dialog and using functions like message.getCurrentTextColor() to get attributes. I ran my code, copied them, and then pasted/hardcoded those values into textview.setTextColor() etc..

A horrible way to do it and a massive waste of time, but nobody else knows of a way to do better. This isn't protected against random changes in default styling of dialogs that may take place as android evolves/changes aesthetically.

Here's an example of me printing the text color into the log

```
TextView tv = (TextView)alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
Log.println(Log.ERROR,String.valueOf(tv.getCurrentTextColor()), String.valueOf(tv.getCurrentTextColor()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The eseyest way that you can use HTML

To cuostom your text

It will work fine with you

You can use it in jlabel jtextvew jtextarea or jtextfield

So use html :)